# C++ Multidimensional Array help delete a row and column

Tags: multidimensional-array

I need someone to tell me how to write a code easy and understandable for this matrix
In this exercise is search to delete a row and a column:
`const int n = 4, m = 4;
int A[n][m] = { { 2, -8, -7, 5 },{ 4, -7, -8, 2 },{ 1, 10, 3, 6 },{ 4, 7, 9, -3 } };
int i, j, r, k, B[n][m];`

variable r stands for row which need to be deleted
variable k stands for column which needs to be deleted
B[n][m] stands for new matrix that will be showed on console
Waiting for answer
there's my code :

```
    const int n = 4, m = 4;
int A[n][m] = { { 2, -8, -7, 5 },
{ 4, -7, -8, 2 }, 
{ 1, 10, 3, 6 },
{ 4, 7, 9, -3 } };
int i, j, r, k, B[n][m];
cout << "give a value r and k:";
cin >> r >> k;
for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
{
    for (j = 0; j < m; j++)
    {
        if ((i < r) && (j < k))
            B[i][j] = A[i][j];
        if ((i >= r) && (j < k))
            B[i][j] = A[i + 1][j];
        if ((i < r) && (j >= k))
            B[i][j] = A[i][j + 1];
        if ((i >= r) && (j >= k))
            B[i][j] = A[i + 1][j + 1];
    }
}
cout << "Matrix B ={" << endl;
for (i = 0; i < n - 1; i++)
{
    for (j = 0; j < m - 1; j++)
    {
        cout.width(3);
        cout << B[i][j];
    }
    cout << endl;
```

but here is what mix up things to me :
    if ((i < r) && (j < k))
                B[i][j] = A[i][j];
            if ((i >= r) && (j < k))
                B[i][j] = A[i + 1][j];
            if ((i < r) && (j >= k))
                B[i][j] = A[i][j + 1];
            if ((i >= r) && (j >= k))
                B[i][j] = A[i + 1][j + 1];
        }
this is the part where i mess up more often
Can somebody tell me more easier way ?

Comment: _"Waiting for answer"_...  waiting to see what have you tried.

Comment: i edit it :) you have my part how i have done it